# ML Engine: Easiest Way to Get GCS File onto Machine

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I'm submitting an ML Engine training job that calls some of my Python code.  I'd like to download a specific file of mine from on Google Cloud Storage, for use in my code.

What is the best way of doing this?  I can think of a few options:

The only option that comes to mind is using python's `subprocess` to run `gsutil cp gs://project/my_file`. However, I don't know if ML Engine instances have `gsutil` set up by default.  Do they?

Is there an easier way to download a file stored on GCS programatically?  I've looked through the docs but don't see this use case addressed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From within your trainer program, you can use TensorFlow to directly read a file from GCS:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
with file_io.FileIO('gs://bucket/file.csv', 'r') as f:
  ...
```

Of course, you could read & write immediately:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
with file_io.FileIO('gs://bucket/file.csv', 'r') as infile:
  with file_io.FileIO('/tmp/file.csv', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Second best option is to use the Python client library (make sure to specify google-cloud-storage as a dependency):

```
   import google.cloud.storage as gcs
   bucket = gcs.Client().get_bucket('bucketname')
   blob = bucket.blob('/some/file.csv')
   dest = '/tmp/file.csv'
   blob.download_to_filename(dest)
```

Comment: thanks for the help!  It looks like certain TensorFlow functions allow you to specify a GCS path (although the docs aren't super clear).  For example, `tf.data.experimental.make_batched_features_dataset` seems to create a `PrefetchDataset` when passed a GCS path?

Comment: Yes, TensorFlow uses file_io and glob throughout, so anywhere you see file_pattern etc. you can specify wildcards like gs://bucket/some/dir/train* and it will work transparently.

Comment: What if I am using non-public storages? Can I use gfile with a service account? Also: What about local development? gfile is able to read/write files on my local file system but is this possible with `google.cloud.storage` as well?

Comment: Yes, as long as the service account has permissions to access the files, it will work. I'm not sure about requestor-pays buckets, though, because I don't think you have a way to specify a billing account.